# Check to see if array is empty followed by while condition

Tags: php

I have code that does a query, gets the results and then preforms an action on those results. I want to make sure the query doesn't return empty otherwise the while condition will fail.

```
$ckey = $GLOBALS['ckey'];
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM uc_users WHERE id = $ckey;";
$result3 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query3);

if(!empty(mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
{
  while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
  {
    $GLOBALS['cname'] = $row3['display_name'];
  }
}
else{ echo "empty";}
```

This returns " Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:"

```
$ckey = $GLOBALS['ckey'];
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM uc_users WHERE id = $ckey;";
$result3 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query3);

if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_fetch_array($result3)))
{
  while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
  {
    $GLOBALS['cname'] = $row3['display_name'];
  }     
}
else{ echo "empty";}
```

returns "Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in C:"

Comment: Try `mysqli_num_rows($result3)`

Answer (score 0):

On your second code try this:

```
if( mysqli_num_rows($result3) )
```